# Spark AR Studio Camera Event and Count Down Timer

Tags: javascript, facebook, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to implement a countdown timer on camera click for Facebook's Spark AR Studio.

My client wants an AR filter whereby a countdown timer appears when the camera is pressed and then the photo flashes at the end of the timer.

So I would need code that sets up a listener for a camera click event, disables the camera, creates a timer from 3-0, and then renables the camera...

Is this even possible? I'm on a short timeline so I'm hoping to find some tutorials or code examples quickly...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to disable or programatically activate Device's camera and I couldn't find such in the docs but take a look at the `CameraInfoModule` https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/camerainfomodule#properties

You could do some effect when the camera is capturing photo

```js
const CameraInfo= require('CameraInfo');

(async () => {
  CameraInfo.isCapturingPhoto.onOn().subscribe(
    () => { /* code that would be activated when photo is taken */ }
  );
})();
```